# CSS (Mistral) font face not working on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, fonts

I have download the Mistral Font for wordpress site, working fine but not in mobile view, any suggestions please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The browsers used on mobile devices are cut-down versions of those used on desktop/laptop machines. As such they often do not support several CSS features that the desktop version routinely supports for years, e.g. certain newish element properties and less common fonts. One thing you might try is including font folders for all the website's fonts. In this way you are independent of the ability of the browser (and indeed of any CDN or Google API) to import the font for you - it's already available in the website files. See:  https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this link in the head section :

```
<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/1cfac2832ad49f16a3ea6b5c2287af2f?family=Mistral" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: did you try google fonts?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mistral"/>  . . . won't work as Mistral isn't a Google font. But according to this webpage https://www.cdnfonts.com/mistral.font  we can use a CDN  to get it into our HTML header: **<link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/mistral" rel="stylesheet">**  And it works !

Comment: Like how ? Like this: <link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mistral:400,700'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  ?  That doesn't work either.  And that's because Google Fonts do **not** carry Mistral. https://fonts.google.com/?query=Mistral  End of story.